# Create a dummy if variable change

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a data frame like this:

```
      cod  ano partido_prefeito
1  110001 1998             <NA>
2  110001 1999             <NA>
3  110001 2000             <NA>
4  110001 2001              PPB
5  110001 2002              PPB
6  110001 2003              PPB
7  110001 2004              PPB
8  110001 2005              PDT
9  110001 2006              PDT
10 110001 2007              PDT
11 110001 2008              PDT
12 110001 2009              PTN
13 110001 2010              PTN
14 110001 2011              PTN
15 110001 2012              PTN
```

The data frame contains much more information
The same sequence of years for each different cod.
What I want to create is a new variable called maybe "dummy_pref" which is 1 when the variable "partido_prefeito" changes, except when is NA and 0 otherwise. Like this:

```
      cod  ano partido_prefeito dummy_pref
1  110001 1998             <NA>          0
2  110001 1999             <NA>          0
3  110001 2000             <NA>          0
4  110001 2001              PPB          0
5  110001 2002              PPB          0
6  110001 2003              PPB          0
7  110001 2004              PPB          0
8  110001 2005              PDT          1
9  110001 2006              PDT          0
10 110001 2007              PDT          0
11 110001 2008              PDT          0
12 110001 2009              PTN          1
13 110001 2010              PTN          0
14 110001 2011              PTN          0
15 110001 2012              PTN          0
```

I thought about something using group_by(cod) and then mutate, but I don't know how to call the mutate. It's not a identification, it's a dummy
Thanks!

Comment: Try wtih `df %>% group_by(cod) %>% mutate(dummy_pref = partido_prefeito != lag(partido_prefeito))`

Comment: It gives a collum if TRUE or FALSE, not 0 or 1

Comment: I was about to change it bfore it got duplicated.

Comment: The problem is the question is not duplicated. The question linked is different from mine, can u help me?

Comment: I can't help you in that aspect.  You may have to message the person who dupe linked.  I

Comment: You can change the code to `df %>% group_by(cod) %>% mutate(ind =  replace_na(as.integer(partido_prefeito != lag(partido_prefeito) & !is.na(partido_prefeito)), 0))`